# How to update table using rank function

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table test(
e_id NUMBER(10),
code NUMBER(10),
active NUMBER(1)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES(11,0,NULL);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(11,0,NULL);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(11,3,NULL);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(12,1,NULL);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(12,3,NULL);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(12,4,NULL);

DB version: Oracle 18c
```

I need to find the minimum  `code` from the table  `test` grouping `e_id`. If we have same values after finding the minimum one then need to update the  `active` column to 1. Basically, need to find out the minimum  `code` value and update the first record to 1 in `active` column.

My attempt:

```
SELECT e_id, code, rnk FROM (
SELECT t.*,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e_id ORDER BY code ASC) AS rnk
FROM test t
);
```

This will give me the rank of the rows and if I filter based `rnk=1` then will give the result but how to update the table in this scenario?

Expected output:

```
+------+------+--------+--+
| E_ID | CODE | ACTIVE |  |
+------+------+--------+--+
|   11 |    0 | 1      |  |
|   11 |    0 | NULL   |  |
|   11 |    3 | NULL   |  |
|   12 |    1 | 1      |  |
|   12 |    3 | NULL   |  |
|   12 |    4 | NULL   |  |
+------+------+--------+--+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option; `row_number` is better in this case because `rank` will "mark" all duplicate rows with `1`, but you need only one.

Before:

```
SQL> select * from test order by e_id, code;

      E_ID       CODE     ACTIVE
---------- ---------- ----------
        11          0
        11          0
        11          3
        12          1
        12          3
        12          4

6 rows selected.
```

Update (actually, merge):

```
SQL> merge into test a
  2    using (select s.rid
  3           from (select rowid rid,
  4                        row_number() over (partition by t.e_id order by t.code) rnk
  5                 from test t
  6                ) s
  7           where s.rnk = 1
  8          ) x
  9    on (x.rid = a.rowid)
 10  when matched then update set
 11    a.active = 1;

2 rows merged.
```

After:

```
SQL> select * from test order by e_id, code;

      E_ID       CODE     ACTIVE
---------- ---------- ----------
        11          0          1
        11          0
        11          3
        12          1          1
        12          3
        12          4

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you please let me know why we have used rowid and row number? Can't we achieve this using rank function?

Comment: ROWID is here so that you'd know which row to update (as there's no unique identifier in the table). RANK returns "duplicates" - in your example, the first two rows for E_ID = 11, whose CODE = 0, would have RANK = 1 but you want to update only one. So, you'd then have to choose which one of these to update, and that's some more coding you don't really want - ROW_NUMBER - in this case - is a better option.